# JBoss&Hibernate

Tags: eclipse, jboss, classloader, jboss7.x, eclipse-indigo

I'm using JBoss AS 7.1 and Hibernate in Eclipse 3.7.2 to build a Dynamic Web Project using Java and JSP. All of the proper JAR files are in the WAR (I checked), but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3DTDEntityResolver from [Module "deployment.MyProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.reset(Configuration.java:326)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:265)
        org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:269)
        my.project.MyManager.<init>(MyManager.java:79)
        org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:68)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:326)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:253)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

The relavent line of the manager class is `Configuration cfg = new Configuration();`. Everything works perfectly in a standalone eclipse project. It only breaks when I try to make a JBoss Page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, apparently the problem was trying to include hibernate jars at all. JBoss AS 7.1.1 has hibernate built in. You have to add `Dependencies: org.hibernate, org.hibernate.envers` to `MANIFEST.MF`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the hibernate-annotations.jar is properly setup in your WAR file. It's probably missing.

Comment: I completely removed everything besides hibernate-core, hibernate-c3p0, and c3p0, and the error still occurs. It has nothing to do with annotations. I can load just about every other class from that jar, just not EJB3DTDEntityResolver.

Comment: I think that's the point, in my research I found that that class is in hibernate-annotations.jar. Can you verify that in the files you have?  (just open the Jar file in Emacs or unpack it to see). If that's the case, you need that Jar file.

Comment: It is present in both the core and the annotations jar. And I did have the annotations jar in my classpath when I ran into this. I then switched to not-annotations are removed all but the listed jars.